# Not able to insert data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert the Oracle EMP table data in one of the database (created "SCOTT") in MySQL.

```
INSERT INTO EMP 
VALUES (7788,'SCOTT','ANALYST',7566,STR_TO_DATE('13-JUL-1987','%d-%m-%Y'),3000,NULL,20);
```

is not working. This insertion is giving error:

> Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '13-JUL-1987' for function
>   str_to_date

please help me on this?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Format specifier](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for the 3-letter Abbreviated Month Name is `%b`, and not `%m`:

```
INSERT INTO EMP 
VALUES (7788,'SCOTT','ANALYST',7566,STR_TO_DATE('13-JUL-1987','%d-%b-%Y'),3000,NULL,20);
```

> `%m`  Month, numeric (00..12)
>
> `%b`  Abbreviated month name (Jan..Dec)